# Как можно по условию переданному в конструктор, выбрать переопределяемые методы в C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, ооп

Есть дочерний класс, он оверайдит некоторые методы родительского. И вопрос в том, как можно заоверайдить только те методы, которые нужны предположим по каким то условиям. Возможно это проще через рефлексию сделать или через какой то алгоритм.

Для примера:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void TestA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }

    public virtual void TestB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(bool condition) 
    {
        if (condition)
            // если true переопределить один метод, иначе два метода
    }

    public override void TestA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("testA");
    }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы в классе **B** можно было скажем по параметрам переданным в конструктор переопределить только нужный метод, или методы, заранее не зная что будет передано.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При переопределении метода, всегда можно вызывать оригинальную реализацию через ключевое слово `base`:

```
public override void TestA() {
  if (this.condition)
    Console.WriteLine("TestA");
  else base.TestA();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужен не один класс, а два:

```
public class B : A
{
    public override void TestA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("testA");
    }
}

public class B1 : B
{
    public override void TestB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("testB");
    }
}
```

И такой простой фабричный метод:

```
public static class BFactory
{
    public static B Create(bool condition)
        => condition ? new B() : new B1();
}
```

Теперь, вместо использования конструктора `new B()`, используйте этот метод:

```
var b = BFactory.Create(/*здесь ваше выражение*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Uranus все правильно написал. Приведу просто полный код для класса B:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void TestA()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A: testA");
    }

    public virtual void TestB()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A: testB");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    private readonly bool _condition;

    public B(bool condition)
    {
        _condition = condition;
    }

    public override void TestA()
    {
        if (_condition)
            Console.WriteLine("B: testA");
        else
            base.TestA();
    }
}
```